# How to connect MySQL with python 3

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

everyone I am new to python and I want to connect MySQL database with python 3 script. I did some googling but couldn't find anything for python 3 although there are methods for earlier python releases. Could anyone suggest a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL-Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/), [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/) and [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) all support Python 3. They are also all supported by [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html), which also supports Python 3.

So most likely you's want to use SQLAlchemy + one of the above conectors.